# ReactJS->Why are my products shown in such a way?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I have a React app where I have a list of products that I am mapping over and then I show them to the user and it all works fine, until I get on the second row(it is 4 products on a row) and it shows just 3 products and and empty space(that turned out to be the html of the page showing itself over there for some reason) and the 4th product is on the new row. Why is that happening? My guess is that it is something with either my CSS or something within the map function, here's my map function:

```
{productsList.map((product, id)=>
                <div className='productsList' key={id}>
                    <div className='productShow'>
                        <h3 className='productName'>{product.name}</h3>
                        <img className='productImage' src={product.image}></img>
                        <p className='productPrice'><strong>$ {product.price}.99</strong></p>
                        <Button  className='addProductButton' variant='success' onClick={()=>addProduct(product, id)}>
                            <MdAddShoppingCart size={20}></MdAddShoppingCart>
                            <strong>Add to cart </strong>
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>)}
```

and here's my CSS:

```
body, html
{
    background-color:#89ABE3FF;
}
.productImage
{
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10%;
}
.productShow
{
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 5px gray;
    width: 20%;
    height: 25%;
    margin-right: 4.5%;
    margin-top:1.5%;
    padding: 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: right;
    transition: 0.4s linear;
}
.productShow:hover
{
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255,0.9);
    transition: 0.4s linear;
}
.cartIndicator
{
    color: rgb(59, 55, 55);   
    transition: linear 0.6s;
}
.cartIndicator:hover
{
    color:black;  
    transition: linear 0.6s;
}
.navbar
{
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px black;
    background-color:#FCF6F5FF;
}
.addProductButton
{
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.carouselWrapper
{
}

.carouselImage
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem would be that you are using 20% width in class `productShow` ( you could have (`20*5 = 100`) 5 products on the same line.

But you added margin-right 4.5%. So you have 24,5% with margin and width, and this would be `24,5 * 4 = 96 < 100` so you can add 4 elements by row.

Finally, you added padding, so you have 2% padding (1% left- 1% right) and then would be 26,5 each product. So `26,5*4  = 106 > 100` max width parent .Then you can use 3 elements by row `26,5*3 = 79,5`. (`100-79,5 = 20,5` empty space).

Fix

Add this property to `productShow`:

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

[Link box-sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp) how it works.

You will include padding to width and you will have 24,5% width each element. 4 elements by row

Comment: So that would mean that if I remove the padding that would solve the problem since the empty space left would be 2? another alternative would be to change the width

Comment: I'l put on the answer

Comment: It didn't seem to work, that is how my `productShow` looks like:
`.productShow
{
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 5px gray;
    width: 20%;
    height: 25%;
    margin-left: 4.5%;
    margin-top:1.5%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.4s linear;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}`

Comment: check it https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-agnesi-4gc4t?file=/src/styles.css:604-621

Comment: Well, I've tried your solution, it works and in my case it just doesn't really change anything. Might be something else in my code. Another possible solution I have found is to just add `display: inline-block` to the css . I've learnt a lot by your answer and I appreciate that you took the time to answer it and help me so I will accept it :)))

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, and the solution was rather simple. It was not the CSS, nor the images or the way I map the products. It was that I had to apply bootstrap to the div that holds them all.
That's what I had changed:

```
 <div className='productShow col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-2'>
```

I have added `col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-2`to the className, it now works like a charm !